# replace a character at only one postion with respect to a specific string shell script

Tags: bash, shell, replace, scripting

I am trying to replace the bracket ( right before |-> string in the code file. There are other ( brackets too in the same line, but I want to replace the one that is just before this string |-> in each line.
e.g in the line below, I want to replace the second bracket of this line, which is the opening bracket right before the |-> string using a shell script command.

property ( ( req1 == 0 ) |-> ( gnt1 == 0 ) );

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: desired output : property ( ! ( req1 == 0 ) |-> ( gnt1 == 0 ) );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `sed`:

```
echo 'property ( ( req1 == 0 ) |-> ( gnt1 == 0 ) );' | sed 's/\(([^(]*|->\)/! \1/'
```

Prints:

```
property ( ! ( req1 == 0 ) |-> ( gnt1 == 0 ) );
```

The way it works is to look for a `(` (the one after `s/\(`) but only when it's followed by stuff other than `(` (that's `[^(]*` and then `|->`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to do this replacement for every property in the code file. Do I have to echo them all first ? Also every code will have a different set of properties and I would not know them all so I want something generic that can be applied to all, and changes the bracket only before this |-> in every property the code has. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @mii9: No, you can pass the filename to sed instead of using echo, as in `sed 's/.../' FILENAME`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was very helpful.

Comment: @mii9: You're welcome.  If this solved your problem you can "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark on the left.